# Direct print without prompting print dialog in pdfobject

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, pdfobject

Currently I'm using `PDFObject` javaScript library to view/print PDF file.

Is there any way to print a PDF without opening print dialog box (pdf viewer) using JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Direct print without preview/dialog box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667417/direct-print-without-preview-dialog-box)

Answer (score 0):

PDF.js is a Portable Document Format (PDF) viewer that is built with HTML5.

PDF.js is community-driven and supported by Mozilla Labs. Our goal is to create a general-purpose, web standards-based platform for parsing and rendering PDFs.